# Why doesn't putchar(1+'0') output 10?

Tags: c, putchar

Why does putchar outputs '1' for `putchar(1+'0')` but not '10' but when only a character argument is passed, like `putchar('0')`, it outputs it.

With `putchar(1+'0')`, I expected an output of 10.

Comment: Because operators in C behaves as they are specified. They do not necessarily behave like operators in some other random programming language or as you think they should behave. You could however do `puts("1" "0");` to get the behavior you describe.

Comment: `1 + '0' == '1'`.  It's the character whose value is one more than the character value of `'0'`.  It's just integer addition.

Answer (score 7):

`putchar` always outputs a single character only, as per the name.

`'0'` is a single character literal. So it’s an integer value that represents the character `0` in your computer’s encoding — almost certainly ASCII.

`1+'0'` then literally means “the character that comes one after `0` in my computer’s encoding (which is almost certainly ASCII). Which is the character `1`.

Comment: and `putchar(4)` outputs the integer 4. can you explain it for me?

Comment: @ElormCodes1 In a typical, ASCII -compatible character set, 4 is the value of the [␄ character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character).

Comment: @ElormCodes1 refer to this [ASCII-table](https://ascii-tables.com/)

Comment: @ElormCodes1: Re “and `putchar(4)` outputs the integer 4”: No, it does not, if by “integer 4” you actually mean the character “4”. Did you try it?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike languages such as Python, the `+` operator in C is not used to concatenate strings.

What you actually have here with `1+'0'` is that you're adding the value 1 with the character code for the character `0`.  The C standard guarantees that the characters for the numerals `0` to `9` have consecutive character encodings, so adding 1 to the character code for `0` gives you the character code for `1`, which is what gets printed.

Answer (score 3):

Understand that in C, there aren't really chars. They are just integers.

`putchar(48);` prints `"0"`
`putchar(49);` prints `"1"`
`putchar(65);` prints `"A"`

Because 48 is the ascii reprentation of character `0`, 49 of `1`, 65 of `A`. That is not even C decision. That is the terminal job. `putchar` just output the integer it was given as an argument to the output terminal, and it does the job of drawing a nice oval if pushed 48, a nice vertical bar if pushed 49, or a upside down V with a transversal bar if pushed 65 (I described it voluntarily this trivial way to make clear how it is just a drawing convention).

Now, the second thing to understand is that in C, for the same reason (there aren't really chars), there are several ways to write a literal integer. 48 for example can be written
in decimal, `48`
in hexadecimal, `0x30`
in octal, `060`
and in "char" representation, `'0'`.

`'0'` is just a way to type 48.

The only reason why you wouldn't type this code
`printf("Di Caprio is %d years old\n", '0');`
is not because it wouldn't work. It is exactly the same as if you had typed
`printf("Di Caprio is %d years old\n", 48);`

The reason why you don't do that, is because it is an awful style. A human reader of your code would have hard time to understand it. Normally you don't use `'0'` to say `48`, unless you mean "48 as the ascii code of 0"
(Plus, theoretically, you are not supposed to know that 48 is the ascii code of `0`. The whole point of using that notation is to let that decision to the compiler).

So, back to your example, when you said
`putchar(1+'0');`
it is exactly the same code as if you had
`putchar(1+0x30);`
or
`putchar(1+060);`
or
`putchar(1+48);`
so, in the end
`putchar(49);`
and, since 49 is the ascii code of `1`
`putchar('1');`

Answer (score 1):

`'0'` is a literal character constant for the digit character `0`.  In ASCII/ANSI character sets it has a numeric value 0x30 (or 48 decimal).  If you add 1 to it you get a value 0x31 - the character code for `'2'`, and `putchar()` interprets the parameter as a *single* character code and presents the appropriate character to `stdout`.

If you wanted to output `"10"` you would need:

```c
putchar('1') ;
putchar('0') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C a character in single quotes is a `char`. But a `char` in C is also just a number that encodes some ASCII character.

The character `'0'` corresponds corresponds to number 48. So 48 is it's ASCII code.

So when you add an `int` `1` with a `char` `'0'`, the char `'0'` is converted to an `int`. So basically `1 + 48`, which is 49.

Then you try to call `putchar(49)` which converts the `49` to it's ASCII character which is `'1'`.

Comment: The `char` type is used to hold character codes (among other things), but it is not always ASCII. ASCII is very common, but not all C implementations use ASCII, and the C standard does not require it.